# Logfile PHP [PHP]

Tags: php, logfile

I am currently trying to do a logfile where I wanna insert a reverse chronology style (newest items will be put on top of the list of all existing texts, and previous existing items will be pushed below), think of it like Facebook Page, where if you visit a Profile Page, you can see all his posts by latest -> oldest, instead of currently what I have is, oldest -> latest. Here's my code so far;

```
    $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $file = 'logfile.txt';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        $current .= PHP_EOL.$date;
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
    } else {
        file_put_contents($file, $date);
    }
```

Comment: I doubt if that is a really good idea... It prevents to use common tools like `tail -f` or `fail2ban` to monitor such a log file. Are you really talking about what is commonly referred to as a "log file", so a technical documentation, or is this about an event stream that is to be visualized inside an application? If the latter, then use a database instead which allows you to order the entries to your liking later.

Comment: May I ask you what's that function is for ? And how useful is that ?

Comment: A "log file" typically serves administrative purposes: to be able to see what is actually going on inside a system or to find out what has been going on at a certain point in time. Such debugging or analyzing action has nothing to do with the normal operation of applications or services. Such action is done on system level, using system tools. Preventing that seems like a less than ideal approach to me. But as mentioned above: maybe this isn't really about what is usually referred to as a "log file", but merely about an event stream used _inside_ an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your date string to the end of the variable:

```
$current .= PHP_EOL.$date;
```

You need to start with the newest and add the older entries after it:

```
$current = $date . PHP_EOL . $current;
```